# Regex to find all "if" statements without "{"

Tags: regex

I am using `(if\()(.*)(?!\{)`

Doesn't seem to be working...

Example of the if types:

> `if( ( Collection.containsKey( primaryKeyValue ) ) ) {`

Also I want to exclude `else if`

Comment: A regex isn't really the ticket here. If you have e.g. Perl or Python, you could use their multi-line regex support over the whole file in a string, but then you might as well define a simple parser for `if` statements, or find a grammar for your target language.

Comment: What's your program in? perl (or any PCRE)? VI? Emacs? Javascript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This regex matches (most of of time) `if` statement that ends with `;` without using `{`:

```
\bif\s*\([^\{]+;
```

(`\b` is word boundary to make sure that if is alone and is not part of another word like zif).

However, this regex is NOT reliable. Actually, *any* regex solution cannot be 100% reliable here because characters you are matching can be present in strings inside `if` condition.

Consider this example - it will not pass regex above, while it is clearly fine by your rules:

```
if (s.equals(";{;};")) { t="({;})"; }
```

And it will pass on this example, which is wrong by your rules:

```
if (s.equals("{;}")) t="({;})";
```

If you want rock-solid performance here, you must write your own code parser.

Comment: That regex is as reliable as I'd ask for!  TY

Answer (score 3):

An `if` without a scope needs to be terminated by a `;`. So you could just check if there is a `;` somewhere after an `if` before there is a `{`. This regular expression should do it:

```
(if[^{;]*;)
```

Please note that this needs multi-line regular expressions.